# difficulty conceptualizing sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, selection

I'm a bit jammed up on a current reporting issue that I'm hoping to find some help with.

A doctor is retiring. Her patients need to be notified of her retirement. People who constitute as "her patient" have seen her more times than any other doctor in the past two years. Failing that (ie. has seen her and another doctor 2 times each in the past 2 years), they are "her patient" if they went to see her most recently.

Here's what I have, so far.

```
select patient_id, last_name, first_name, post_fromdate, performing_md_id, performing_md_name, category_desc, procedure_code
from [table]
where post_fromdate >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-24)
and category_desc like '%WELL%' --specific visit type
and patient id in ([list of patients])
group by patient_id, last_name, first_name, post_fromdate, performing_md_id, performing_md_name, category_desc, procedure_code
order by patient_id, post_fromdate desc
```

To recap...

What I have: a list of every doctor's visit every patient of the doctor in question, including visits to other doctors.

What I seek: some additional criteria that will indicate if the retiring doctor has been visited the most by each individual patient. If seen equally but not less than the other doctors for a given patient, then if the retiring doctor was visited most recently.

Any assistance is graciously accepted. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: the desired result would be output that gives me the information in the select clause, with one and only one performing_md_id per patient_id indicating that patient's doctor (the doctor they have seen the most times in the past two years. If not that, then the doctor they have seen most recently).

Comment: Post your schema, some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: You will need to have count(visits) in the query - post schema of involved tables.

Comment: Here's the disaster: this is all in one table. This DB system is bandaid solutions all the way down. Even the lifers here have no idea where any information is located.

Comment: I don't understand the edit... I thought the doctor who is retiring is known, and you need to know all the patients who had him as their "primary" doctor. The EDIT says something else - you want to identify the primary doctor for ALL patients. What does that have to do with your original question? (Or do you think it is the only way to solve your original question?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a table in the shape of patient, doc, visit date

```
select patient,[This Doc] as [This DOC Visit Count], [Other Doc] as [Other Doc Visit Count]
into #visit_counts
from (select patient, case when doctor = 'retiring doc' then 'This Doc' else 'Other Doc' end as Doc, visit_date from doc_patient_visit_table ) P
Pivot (count(visit_date) for Doc in ([This Doc],[Other Doc])) Pvt

select patient,[This Doc] as [This DOC Last Visit], [Other Doc] as [Other Doc Last visit]
into #visit_times
from (select patient, case when doctor = 'retiring doc' then 'This Doc' else 'Other Doc' end as Doc, visit_date from doc_patient_visit_table) P
Pivot (max(visit_date) for Doc in ([This Doc],[Other Doc])) Pvt

select patient, [This DOC Visit Count],  [Other Doc Visit Count], [This DOC Last Visit], [Other Doc Last visit]
from #visit_counts t1
join #visit_times t2 on t1.patient = t2.patient
where [This DOC Visit Count] > [Other Doc Visit Count] or ([This DOC Visit Count] = [Other Doc Visit Count] and [This DOC Last Visit] > [Other Doc Last visit])
```

Another Method

```
Select patient, 
sum(case when doc = 'retiring_doc' then 1 else 0 end) as [This DOC Visit Count],
max(case when doc = 'retiring_doc' then visit_date end)  as [This DOC Last Visit],
sum(case when doc != 'retiring_doc' then 1 else 0 end) as [Other Doc Visit Count],
max(case when doc != 'retiring_doc' then visit_date end)  as [Other Doc Last visit]
from from doc_patient_visit_table
group by patient
having sum(case when doc = 'retiring_doc' then 1 else 0 end) > sum(case when doc != 'retiring_doc' then 1 else 0 end) 
OR (sum(case when doc = 'retiring_doc' then 1 else 0 end) = sum(case when doc != 'retiring_doc' then 1 else 0 end)
AND [This DOC Last Visit] > [Other Doc Last visit])
```

Comment: That makes total sense. I'll give it the ol' college try. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. The table and column names are made up, but should be self-explanatory.

```
select patient_id, 
       max(doctor_id) keep (dense_rank last order by ct, last_visit) as primary_doctor_id
from   (
         select   patient_id, doctor_id, count(*) as ct, max(visit_date) as last_visit
         from     visits
         group by patient_id, doctor_id
       )
group by patient_id
;
```